# Incorrect syntax error near offset when Dataset is fetched from SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL I have followed standard procedure for writing but when i fill my dataset exception is caught.As the dataset is not able to access the table.I get exception as incorrect syntax near offset.

My code here:

```
USE [OSO]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[FetchCustomer]    Script Date: 1/5/2017 11:02:18 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[FetchCustomer]
@Type Nvarchar(20),
@Condition Nvarchar(20),
@Start int,
@Length int,
@UserId nvarchar(30),
@ColumnIndex int,
@SortOrder nvarchar(10)
 AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  declare @ColumnName nvarchar(50);
  declare @genericsearchsql nvarchar(max);
  declare @genericsql nvarchar(max);
    if @ColumnIndex=0
        begin
            if exists (select * from SystemSettingsSubForms where SubFormName='CUSTOMERLIST' and FieldName='TABLESORT' and Value<>'0,asc' and Value<>'0,desc' and UserId=@UserId)
                select @ColumnIndex=substring(Value,1,1),@SortOrder=substring(Value,3,4) from SystemSettingsSubForms where SubFormName='CUSTOMERLIST' and FieldName='TABLESORT'
            else
                begin
                    set @ColumnName='Company'
                    set @SortOrder='asc'
                end
        end
        if @ColumnIndex=1
            set @ColumnName='Company'
        else if @ColumnIndex=2
            set @ColumnName='FirstName'
        else if @ColumnIndex=3
            set @ColumnName='Street'
        else if @ColumnIndex=4
            set @ColumnName='City'
        else if @ColumnIndex=5
            set @ColumnName='State'

    set @genericsearchsql='SELECT * FROM Customers where 
            FirstName like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            Company like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            LastName like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            Street like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            City like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            [State] like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%''
            order by '+@ColumnName+' '+@SortOrder+'
            offset @Start rows FETCH NEXT @Length ROWS ONLY';
    set @genericsql='SELECT * FROM Customers order by '+@ColumnName+' '+@SortOrder+' offset @Start rows FETCH NEXT @Length ROWS ONLY'; 


     if(@Type='ALL')
    Begin
      SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM Customers

          exec sp_executesql @genericsql,N'@Start int,@Length int',@Start=@Start,@Length=@Length          
  end
  else if(@Type='CUSTOMERSEARCH')
    Begin
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Customers where  
            (FirstName like '%'+@Condition+'%' or                                       
            Company like '%'+@Condition+'%' or
            Street like '%'+@Condition+'%' or
            [State] like '%'+@Condition+'%' or                                      
            City like '%'+@Condition+'%')

            exec sp_executesql @genericsearchsql,N'@Start int,@Length int',@Start=@Start,@Length=@Length
    end
   END
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: when u execute this proc on sql server side what happens ?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'offset'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: Your sqlserver is 2012 ?

Comment: Connecting any remote instance ? or some other instance ? which is not 2012 and above?

Comment: connecting remote instance only, above sql server 2012 only

Comment: What is the version of your remote instance  ? check that. you can have 2012. but the query is run on the remote instance.

Comment: sorry i dont know to check but other stored procedure with fetch and offset are running fyn in my machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132392/discussion-between-sundar-stalin-and-fakeisme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are building a SQL command, you need to embed the values of @Start and @Length into the string, since they will not be available to the execution context. This version should work.

```
set @genericsearchsql='SELECT * FROM Customers where 
            FirstName like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            Company like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            LastName like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            Street like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            City like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%'' or
            [State] like '''+'%'+@Condition+'%''
            order by '+@ColumnName+' '+@SortOrder+'
            offset ' + CAST(@Start as varchar) + ' rows FETCH NEXT ' + Cast(@Length as varchar) + ' ROWS ONLY';
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're trying to dynamically execute a SELECT, but the following is not valid in a SELECT-statement:</strike>

```
   offset @Start rows FETCH NEXT @Length ROWS ONLY
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this clause, but my guess is, that it's not needed, so I would just remove it.

Comment: Oops, my bad. It is valid SQL

Comment: yes @tony can execute if you have an idea to resolve it pls tell me